# Crispy pork belly, how can I cook the inside more?

Tags: pork, pork-belly

I recently discovered that there is an Asian market in my neighborhood. I was thrilled to discover it. I ended up purchasing a bit of pork belly cooked on-site and highly recommended by the owner. She said (rightfully) that her pork belly was crisper than any pork belly I'd ever seen. The crusty outside is very, very nice. Unfortunately, the inside still has that unrendered, solid quality.

I've tried slicing it through the center and frying it (cut side down) over a low flame. That left the beautiful crust overcooked. I could slice away the crust, I suppose, but I'd rather not dissect it that much. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried baking it?

Comment: [This stuff](https://www.google.de/search?q=thit+heo+quay&tbm=isch)? :D

Comment: @ChingChong Yep! Hers looks very much like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--kuyLXYJXoE/UpHyZRocBeI/AAAAAAAARmo/mTZnTJ3ORMg/s550/heoquay.jpg)

Comment: @jsanc623 I have not tried baking it, just because the crust is already so well done. If I end up dissecting it (slicing off the crust), then baking (roasting) would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Yum, tasty pork but these are just concentrated calories :(

Comment: I have to admit that I slice off the crust, too - but for other reasons (trim the loads of fat). I still can't visualize how the inside of your piece looks like :o

Comment: @ChingChong The inner part just looks almost raw. You know, one nice thing about slicing off the crusts, is that I could marinate the inner layer with rich Asian flavors. Then slow cook that, and serve it all together. Maybe with pancakes and hoisin! :)

Comment: Asians like food more chewy, tough. ;) If you would like to have your pork more tender, you probably won't be able to avoid dissecting it. About the rawness: I never had an almost raw piece.

Answer (score 2):

It might be sacrilege, but how about microwaving briefly? The crust won't burn anymore, but the heat will help render the fat. Worth a shot. But probably not the best flavor.

I'd probably experiment with pan frying some slices at different temperatures to see if you can get the meat and fat done before you over char the crust. Try slicing it vertically into 1/4" slices with the crust on the top 1/4" edge. That will minimize the crust and maximize the surface area of the inside.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [this method for carnitas](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/07/no-waste-tacos-de-carnitas-with-salsa-verde-recipe.html) as seen on Serious Eats. Essentially you place the pork in a snug fitting dish, not-quite-cover it in oil, cover it with foil and bake it low and slow. The foil should protect the crust from burning, but it might make it a little soggy, in which case you could take the foil off towards the end of cooking to crisp it up again.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to slow roast the pork belly if you want the interior meat to render. Then either crank up the heat in the oven (to 450F or higher, for example), or put it under the broiler, to finish. That will give you a nice and tender inside, with a crispy outside.

Comment: If I end up cutting off the crusts (I'm specifically looking to use the belly cooked by the lady at the market), then I think you're right about how to best cook the inner layer.